# Rails Postgres Schema references rollback issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-schema, rails-migrations

In my rails application I have multiple postgresql schemas.

```
SHOW search_path;

search_path
--------------
"$user",public,vehicle
```

I have two tables (dealers, inventories) in the vehicle schema. The relationship holds like this:

```
dealer has_many inventories
inventory belongs_to dealer
```

I created a migration to add the relationship as:

```
class AddDealerIdToVehicleInventories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference 'vehicle.inventories', :dealer, index: true, foreign_key: {on_delete: :cascade}
  end
end
```

This migration works perfectly when I run: `rake db:migrate`, the foreign_key seems added to the table without any issue. But when I run `rake db:rollback`, I am getting this error message:

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "vehicle.dealer_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "vehicle"."inventories" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_95ee16593d"
FOREIGN KEY ("vehicle.dealer_id")
  REFERENCES "vehicle"."dealers" ("id")
 ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I am not sure if I am making any mistakes or is the rails migration bug. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by making changes in the migration file as:

```
class AddDealerIdToVehicleInventories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_reference 'vehicle.inventories', :dealer, index: true, foreign_key: {on_delete: :cascade}
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TABLE vehicle.inventories
        DROP COLUMN dealer_id
    SQL
  end
end
```

Hope, this is useful for others too.